# How to do a manual fold in vim, when your foldmethod is set to syntax

Tags: vim

In vim I use the set foldmethod=syntax while browsing through my C/C++ code. But in some cases like when I'd like to ignore some #ifdef code, I'd like to select a portion of the code visually and use zf to fold that section of the code.

I tried doing this but ended up getting the following error :

> E350: Cannot create fold with current 'foldmethod'

Is there any way to use manual folding while not messing with my default settings?

Comment: The value of `:help 'foldmethod'` determines what method you can use. If you want to use a different method temporarily, change the value of the option.

Comment: @romainl  think that's a bit inefficient, does that mean for each time I want some custom fold, I go and change the foldmethod and then reset it back. I hope there is some way to do this without changing foldmethod, I don't understand why zf doesn't work, it seems like a good way to override the syntax based folding since that usually uses zc zo etc..

Comment: Efficient or not, there is no built-in alternative. You only have one active method for the current window and there is nothing you can do about it. I mean… `:help zf` even explicitly says *This only works when 'foldmethod' is "manual" or "marker".*. With that in mind, you could write a little mapping that toggles the method or one that splits the window, sets the option and does `zf`, or something like that.